# How to spoof session cookie to test Session Replication

Tags: java, session, jboss

How can I spoof session cookie to test Session Replication?

I am using Jboss on two nodes and I want to confirm that if one node goes down my session data is in the other node.

I can see that my node 1 is setting this cookie. How can I spoof it for node 2?

```
JSESSIONID=3rsZ87MxC7EeukilWW8za7T-.node1; path=/hsr-test; domain=xxxx.xxxx.dev
```

Comment: Spoofing is a very specific term used in terms of security (e.g. ip spoofing). Did you mean verify instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response, but added since I was searching on this.

Here's a simple session get/put jsp script

```
    <html>
    <body>

        <a href="testsession.jsp?action=put">put</a>
        <a href="testsession.jsp?action=get">get</a>
    <%
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if ( null != action && "put".equals(action) ) {
    %>
            <h2>Set Current Time</h2>
    <%
            System.out.println( "Putting date now" );
            session.setAttribute("current.time", new java.util.Date());
    %>
            The time is set to <%= session.getAttribute("current.time") %>
    <% } else { %>
            <h2>Get Time</h2>
    <%
            System.out.println( "Getting date now" );
    %>
            The time is <%= session.getAttribute("current.time") %>
    <% } %>

    <br>
    <br>
    server: <%=request.getServerName() %>

    <br>
    <br>
    session: <%= session.getId() %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If you are on the command line, you can use this on both nodes:

```
curl --cookie "JSESSIONID=ZWarGbkuDUoUuT-iOjYIATN+.2e84d3e9-3497-3e74-9604-a45f36cad465;"  http://node1/your_test_page

curl --cookie "JSESSIONID=ZWarGbkuDUoUuT-iOjYIATN+.2e84d3e9-3497-3e74-9604-a45f36cad465;"  http://node2/your_test_page
```

You'll see the time returned in the browser and both command line tests.

Answer (score 0):

Session replication is performed by default in JBoss as long as the application is running in a cluster and has `<distributable>` set in the `WEB-INF\web.xml` file.

You can verify that the session has been replicated by login to the jmx-console of each node in the cluster and invoke the method `printCacheDetails()` for the `jboss.cache` package `ha-partition, cache-config` MBean. The session data should get printed for the nodes respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can use Fiddler. Run Fiddler alongside your application, then enable breakpoints before requests (Rules -> Automatic Breakpoints -> Before Requests). Make a query to a server you want. It will freeze before executing the request and on the top right you can modify (spoof) the cookies by right-clicking the session ID and entering whatever values you want.

Hope this is helpful. I ran across this question by chance researching another issue.